# Any one knows how to achieve this or embed this on custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress

In some new themes, when you provide source link of an article it generates the favicon automatically. anyone know how i can do this on my theme?

http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-3637-111.html

Thanks

Comment: A site should have only one favicon, not a favicon by article, why don't you jsut generate your favicon and add it to your website, you can use a generator like : http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/

Comment: I want to archive this dynamically. Like when you paste the link it will show the faviocn. Thanks for your reply

Comment: But you should have a favicon first, do you ?